# torch.cuda.is_avaiable returns False with nvidia-smi not working

Tags: docker, pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to build a docker image that can run using GPUS, this my situation:
[image: situation inside docker images]

I have python 3.6 and I am starting from image nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-devel.
Torch does not see my GPUs.

`nvidia-smi` is not working too, returning error:

```
> Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error
> The command '/bin/sh -c nvidia-smi' returned a non-zero code: 255
```

I installed nvidia toolkit and nvidia-smi with

```
 RUN apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit -y
 RUN apt-get install nvidia-utils-410 -y
```

Comment: If nvidia-smi fails, your driver installation is broken, or the version of the driver utilities inside the docker container don't match the host system driver version. Neither of your questions are CUDA programming related questions and I will soon removed the CUDA tag from both. Also, should the first question be closed as a duplicate of this?

Comment: If you started with image `nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-devel` there shouldn't be a need to install the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` and definitely no reason to install `nvidia-utils-410`. That second install broke the image. Instead, you should start with the `nvidia/cuda` image you desire (e.g. the CUDA version and CUDNN version you would like to use) and don't install anything that has to do with GPU driver components, which is what the `-410` indicates. Instead, make sure your base machine is set up with [the NVIDIA container toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) and latest GPU driver

Comment: @RobertCrovella I installed those because before when I didn't `nvidia-smi` returned "/bin/sh: 1: nvidia-smi: not found". The nvidia container toolkit is installed in the base machine (for example `docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi` works nicely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem is you can't use nvidia-smi during building (RUN nvidia-smi). Any check related to the avaiability of the GPUs during building won't work.

Using CMD bin/bash and typing the command `python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())'`, I finally get True.
I also removed

```
RUN apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit -y
RUN apt-get install nvidia-utils-410 -y
```

as suggested from @RobertCrovella